# C# - Hide button if tabindex = 0 (Main Tab), otherwise always display

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to work out some code for a tabControl in my program. I want the program to hide a specific button if the main tabIndex = 0 (the main tab). In the event, a new tab is open or selected it will display the button. When the user closes a specific tab, it will check if returned to the main tab the hide the button. Below is what i have coded. So far, it only works if i call it on form load.

```
 if (this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            btCloseReport.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        btCloseReport.Visible = true;
```

Thanks

Dv

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe you need to add your hiding button logic, into tabControlIndexChange event. In that way, you will get the current index, every time you change it.

Comment: Thanks Jasc24 you were correct. I added a TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged Event and its not working perfectly.

Comment: you're welcome @David

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i follow Jasc24's advice and added a TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged Event

```
private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

 if (this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            btCloseReport.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        btCloseReport.Visible = true;}
```

Link here for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You can one-line it like this: `btCloseReport.Visible = (tabControl1.SelectedIndex != 0);`